# How play one stream by multiply VLC player?

Tags: video-streaming, vlc, libvlc

I'm trying to streaming video by this command:

```
$ vlc [path to file] --sout udp:// [destination path]
```

And also on destination, i run two VLC players which play one stream by command:

```
$ vlc udp:// [source path]
```

When i run first player it play video but when i run second player first player stopping and only second player play stream.

How i can play one stream by 2 players?

Answer (score 0):

I assume destination path is the IP and port of the player, meaning you are unicasting the stream directly to that endpoint. When you open the stream on the player it binds to that socket and reads the packets. After that the packets are "gone". Normally the player would reserve the address so no other program can open a socket there, but it seems like this is not happening here, so the second player hijacks the same socket and gets the UDP packets.

If both players are on the same host, multicast will not work either. If there is a fixed number of players you need to support, you can let VLC duplicate the output;

--sout '#duplicate{dst=rtp{mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.10,port=50002},
dst=rtp{mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.40,port=50004}}'

If you need to support an unknown number of clients dynamically, you need to put a streaming server in the mix. Which one really depends on what you want to achieve. Might be that VLC can act as a streaming server directly as well, but I've never tried.

Comment: --sout '#duplicate{dst=rtp{mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.10,port=50002}, dst=rtp{mux=ts,dst=192.168.1.40,port=50004}}'

This method have one problem for me: i have a lot of memory and i cant use more then i have, but packet duplicate need for some memory(because use VLM and it need memory). May i  read data from port to some array and send it to several vlc players and clear array memory using callback from vlc?

Answer (score 0):

For your case, it would be beneficial to have some utility that will replicate UDP packets sent to particular port to several other ports on the same machine.

Implementation of this application should be trivial.